# TinyMCE Custom Color can't edit RGB text on modal

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE on modal bootstrap, I want to use the custom color plugin to add color that doesn't exist on the tinyMCE..

I know the color code that I want to use, but I can't focus to the textbox to input my color code on custom color popup

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap modal has code that stops anything else from getting focus while it is enabled (by design).  You should be able to override this with code like the following:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```

(This assumes you are don't mind using jQuery)

Comment: It's still cannot focus on textbox in the color picker popup

Comment: here's the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/spyrnqp3/1/ try to open the modal and choose custom color on text color, the text won't focus

Comment: Adding the JS I have in my answer allows me to type values into the text boxes:  https://jsfiddle.net/wb7a6t02/

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to include this method http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target Is that causing other problem ? because in my case, it's still cannot focus on the textbox...

Comment: please, kindly to check my fiddle in here https://jsfiddle.net/spyrnqp3/1/ @Michael Fromin

Comment: The fiddle you reference does not seems to rely on related target at all.  As I showed in my earlier response bootstrap by default is not allowing anything else to gain focus so if you add the JS I provided to your Fiddle it will allow focus to happen.   https://jsfiddle.net/wb7a6t02/  If things are not working for you please update your Fiddle to the exact setup you have as what you provided in the Fiddle works perfectly if you add the JS I provided.

Comment: I'm sorry, I give you a wrong fiddle link. Here's the new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/spyrnqp3/2/ . I use method "modal related traget" from the bootstrap, and it makes the textbox cannot get the focus. Please kindly to see it @Michael Fromin

Comment: I moved the focus call to its own `on('shown.bs.modal...`  https://jsfiddle.net/spyrnqp3/4/ and things now work fine for me.

Comment: I don't realize that was different, btw, thankyou very much @MIchael Fromin , I will make your answer as the solution